# Catch serial port stream to the database

Tags: c#, string, winforms, stream, serial-port

I'm stuck with an application that should receive data from serial port streaming (industrial weights) from that string I have to cut weigh value only and send it to a database.

The only problem I met was catching the line and cutting the weigh value.

Here is what I do to catch the serial stream into the textBoxes field:

```
public void write_to_field(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (textBox1.Text.Length <= Convert.ToInt16(strLenghBox.Text))
     {
           string DispString;
           DispString = serialPort1.ReadLine();
           textBox1.AppendText(DispString);
      }
      else
      {
           textBox1.Text = "";
      }
 }
```

In texbox field I have continuous dataflow and I clear the textBox when the character number in it reaches every (strLenghBox.Text) number of characters.

But it works not correct since I have offset (I might begin getting the string not from its beginning and I will get and offset) and also I cant catch weigh value to pass it to the database since the field is not full all the time and I have an offset.

I think I might going wrong way in this situation.

Comment: I actually launch that method this way:        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
                      
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(write_to_field));

        }

Comment: You can check these links - http://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bethmassi/2007/05/05/reading-from-a-serial-port-and-saving-to-a-database and http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/35775-serial-port-communication-in-c%23/

Comment: Hi there. A number of folks in our community sometimes say that every time they see gendered assumptions about software engineers, they worry about people feeling excluded. I wonder, could you try to avoid adding male-oriented greetings and pronouns in your posts, so as to make for a more welcoming environment? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You're trying to retrieve data from a source which can send fragmented data. To ensure data integrity, you'll likely need :

- A Queue to pile data regardless of the format from the stream
- A method to depile data until a complete value is retrieved or the Queue is empty
- A method to detect that a complete value have been retrieved (you've been unclear how data is separated in your stream, for example a separator such as a newline)

This way you separate data reading from value detection and display.